No puedo manipular datos recibidos por props cuando ser carga el componente, pero si los puedo ver por consola
Estoy teniendo un problema al intentar manipular datos que recibo por props en un componente de React. El flujo es el siguiente: desde un componente padre realizo un fecth dentro de un useEffect y guardo los datos, paso estos datos al componente hijo mediante props. Cuando realizo un console.log en el componente hijo para verificar que los datos se están recibiendo correctamente, puedo verlos correctamente en la consola del navegador. Sin embargo, cuando intento manipular esos datos dentro del componente hijo, obtengo un error que indica que los datos son undefined.
He intentado varias soluciones, como pasar los datos por un contexto de React, pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema. Lo más extraño es que si realizo algún cambio en el código del componente (incluso si es un cambio que no tiene relación con la manipulación de los datos), como agregar un espacio en blanco, de repente puedo acceder y manipular los datos correctamente.
Lo que necesito es poder manipular los datos recibidos por props tan pronto como el componente se carga, sin tener que realizar ningún cambio adicional en el código. ¿Alguien ha experimentado un problema similar o tiene alguna idea de qué podría estar causando este comportamiento inesperado?
Ayuda por favor



Por favor el código como texto, cuando agregas imágenes de igual forma te dice que no las uses para compartir código, hay que leer.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Los datos los estas imprimiendo en un useEffect, por lo que se van a imprimir correctamente "cuando llegan".
Si estas intentando usar esos datos en la funcion "render" de tu componente, recuerda que esta se ejecuta antes que el useEffect, enteonces:
Dependiendo de como tengas tu funcion render, yo por lo general solo tengo el return, quedaría algo asi:
const DataCalculation = ({datosPorFondo}) => {
    ///todo tu codigo actual
    return datosPorFondo //aqui estarías validando si ya existen los datos
    ?(
        //Tu codigo en el que usas los datos por fondo
    )
    :(
        //Tu manejo de la espera de los datos
        <CircularProgress /> //por ejemplo un circular progress
    );
};

Éxito!
